# JavaScript React Slider can't hide the next arrow button when no images on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js

I am showing n number of images inside a div depends on screen size. Currently, I am hiding the previous button when the `currentIndex != 0` but can't hide the next button when I don't have any images in my div. see the screenshot [image]

my code here.

```
/image_slider
const containerRef = useRef(null);
const [containerWidth, setContainerWidth] = useState(0);
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const updateContainerWidth = () => {
    if (containerRef.current) {
      setContainerWidth(containerRef.current.offsetWidth);
    }
  };

  // Initial setup
  updateContainerWidth();

  // Update container width on window resize
  window.addEventListener('resize', updateContainerWidth);

  return () => {
    // Cleanup event listener on component unmount
    window.removeEventListener('resize', updateContainerWidth);
  };
}, []); // Empty dependency array ensures this effect runs only once on mount

const showImages = (direction) => {
  console.log("clicked")
  setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => {
    let newIndex = prevIndex + direction;

    if (newIndex < 0) {
      newIndex = items.length - 1;
    } else if (newIndex >= items.length) {
      newIndex = 0;
    }

    return newIndex;
  });
};
```

my previous and next button

```
 <FaArrowRight size={30} className="fill-orange-500 mb-2" onClick={() => showImages(1)}/>
                {currentIndex != 0 &&
                <FaArrowLeft size={30} className="fill-orange-500 " onClick={() => showImages(-1)}   />
                }
```

my div where showing images

```
   {containerWidth > 0 && (
  <>  
    {items.map((data,index)=>(


      <div key={index}  style={{ display: 'flex', transition: 'transform 0.5s', transform: `translateX(-${currentIndex * containerWidth}px)` }}>.....
```

I am not understanding how to hide the next button or right arrow when I don't have any images on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
{currentIndex < items.length -1 && <FaArrowRight size={30} className="fill-orange-500 mb-2" onClick={() => showImages(1)}/> }
```

will hide it when you are on the last one and when there are no images. If you  need only to hide it when there are no images (but still show it when you are on the last one)

```
{items.length > 0 && <FaArrowRight size={30} className="fill-orange-500 mb-2" onClick={() => showImages(1)}/> }
```

I'm assuming the `items` are available in the rendering part but didn't see its definition in your code (only used in `showImages` function).